# C# DataSet.Tables[0].GetChanges(); always returns all rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have bind `DataGridView` in `C# WinForms` from `text file` as shown below

**onPageLoad**

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add(Column0);
            table.Columns.Add(Column1);
            table.Columns.Add(Column2);
            table.Columns.Add(Column3);

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"/data.txt"))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] parts = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    DeviceIDCounter = DeviceIDCounter + 1;
                    table.Rows.Add(DeviceIDCounter, parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
                }
            }
            dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.Clear();
            dataSet.Tables.Add(table);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            DeviceIDCounter = 0;
```

Now on updating single row in the `dataGridView1`, it always return all rows

**onButtonClick** after updating row

```
DataTable dtRecordsUpdated = dataSet.Tables[0].GetChanges(); //always returning total rows
if (dtRecordsUpdated != null && dtRecordsUpdated.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
   Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
else
{}
```

On the other hand, my other function which is bind `DataGridView` from `SQLServer` is working as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update to DataSource of DGV after you made some changes like this:

```
 ((System.Data.DataTable)this.dataGridView1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Ok that did it. First after binding the data to `DataGridView` I have to invoke `AcceptChanges()` and also after every update. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DataTable.GetChanges Method: Gets a copy of the DataTable that contains all changes made to it since it was loaded or AcceptChanges was last called.

- If you need to catch what has changed you need to AcceptChanges
- You get all the rows because the dataTable considers that all the rows have New.State since you never acceptChanges
- PS : there is no need to create the DataSet if you are just passing the DataTable to the DataGridView